# Encrypt an existing sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, mobile, air

I have a sqlite database containing around 10 to 12 tables filled with data. My Adobe Air application reads that data and presents it to user. I found this [example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html) but it creates database on run time. I can easily create an encryption key while creating database on run time but I have an existing database filled with data and I need to encrypt this file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The SQLConnection class provides the ability to encrypt databases using AES with CCM. This provides both authentication and privacy for data. To encrypt a database, a 16 byte key (specified using a ByteArray) must be specified when the database is created. This key can later be changed using the SQLConnection.reencrypt() method. Encryption imposes a performance penalty on writes to and reads from the database. Encryption is applied to data stored on the disk, but not to a temporary data cache in memory. Encryption is not supported for in-memory databases.

Comment: This is what I found here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html#reencrypt